# How to select <table> like <div> in the MS Html editor?

Tags: javascript, dom-events, editor

If a tag like DIV, MARQUEE or IMG is inserted, it can be selected when clicking anywhere in the tag area. However, if a TABLE is inserted, it can only be selected when clicking on the border of tag area. I have searched for the possible event (`onclick`, `keydown`) defined for DIV, but unfortunately no relevant Javascript code was found.  DesignMode is used for the editor. Anyone knows how to make TABLE  easier to be selected just like a DIV?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it using a `ControlRange` and selecting it. Assuming the table element is stored in a variable called "table":

```
table.onclick = function() {
    if (document.selection.type != "Control") {
        var range = document.body.createControlRange();
        range.add(this);
        range.select();
    }
};
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/DTK8j/

Answer (score 0):

It probably means that table was created so that an event was defined for each cell and possibly each row has an event also.  When you click on any area in the row (if there was not padding given for the cell) the cell event was fired up and detect the cell event first not the row event. Likewise the click on the row will trigger the row event rather than the table event.

So it's difficult, but if you didn't define any event like onclick or any event on each row or cell then you only get the table event; otherwise the defined event on any row or cell will be activated in preference to the table event.